# removing duplicate arrays in multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

For some reason I am having trouble with this, I have a multi-dimensional array in PHP like the following below (MySQL data).  What I want to do is remove any duplicate arrays based on "dealerID".

In the example below, I want to search through the arrays and remove any of duplicate dealerID arrays.

Example, take this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["dealerID"]=>
     string(3) "634"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(15) "Dealer Name String"
    ["Other Name"]=>
    string(15) "Dealer Name String"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["dealerID"]=>
     string(3) "777"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(15) "Dealer Name String"
    ["Other Name"]=>
    string(15) "Dealer Name String"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["dealerID"]=>
     string(3) "777"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(15) "Dealer Name String"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["dealerID"]=>
     string(3) "777"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(15) "Dealer Name String"
    ["Other Name"]=>
    string(15) "Dealer Name String"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["dealerID"]=>
     string(3) "777"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(15) "Dealer Name String"
  }
```

Desired result, only arrays with unique dealerID:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["dealerID"]=>
     string(3) "634"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(15) "Dealer Name String"
    ["Other Name"]=>
    string(15) "Dealer Name String"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["dealerID"]=>
     string(3) "777"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(15) "Dealer Name String"
    ["Other Name"]=>
    string(15) "Dealer Name String"
  }
```

What I have tried:

```
$copy = $array; // create copy to delete dups from
$used = array(); // used emails

  for( $i=0; $i<count($array); $i++ ) {

if ( in_array( $array[$i][0], $used ) ) {
    unset($copy[$i]);
}
else {
    $used[] = $array[$i][0];
}

}
```

and:

```
foreach($dealerList as $key => $subarray) {

    if ( in_array( $dealerList[$subarray], $used ) ) {
            echo "ALREADY";
     }
     else {
          $used[] = $dealerList[$subarray];
           echo "NOT ALREADY";
     }

    }
    #$dealerList = $copy;
```

Comment: OK I will put it in the code above

Comment: `group by dealerID`

Comment: I put the things I tried, there is also a single command that will compare the arrays but I think it doesn't work because my arrays aren't always the same size..

Comment: @MikeQ you have answers below. try them. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr=array(
    array(
        'dealerID'=>344,
        'Name'  => 'sdds',
        'Other Name'
    ),
    array(
        'dealerID'=>400,
        'Name'  => 'sdds',
        'Other Name'
    ),
    array(
        'dealerID'=>400,
        'Name'  => 'sdds',
        'Other Name'
    ),
    array(
        'dealerID'=>347,
        'Name'  => 'sdds',
        'Other Name'
    ),
);


foreach($arr as $key=>$item){
    for($i=$key+1; $i<count($arr);$i++){
        if($item['dealerID']==$arr[$i]['dealerID']){
            unset($arr[$i]);
        }
    }
}
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me what key+1 is doing ?   I seems to be ignoring one of the arrays because of this

Comment: Actually it looks like it's leaving at least one dup ... hmmm

Comment: no just apply and tell, me, actually when it is starting to check it didn't need to check value with itself.... So it's leaving atleast one value. you need to delete duplicate values, not all the values who have duplicates. I belive you need one of them and to remove it's duplicates :)

Comment: @MikeQ you have other answers too. check them and if any-one worked for you Mark+up-vote that. you can up-vote others too if they are useful thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Short solution using `array_values` function:

```
// $arr is your exemplary array from the question
$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $v) {
    $result[$v['dealerID']] = $v;
}
$result = array_values($result);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [dealerID] => 634
            [Name] => Dealer Name String
            [Other Name] => Dealer Name String
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [dealerID] => 777
            [Name] => Dealer Name String
            [Other Name] => Dealer Name String
        )
)
```